# Unable to create pollSCM trigger for Multibranch pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a MultiBranch pipeline job where I want to poll my Github to scan for any new commits and trigger a build, so referring to the documentation I added

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

multibranchPipelineJob('mb-build') {
    displayName('Multi Branch Build')

    orphanedItemStrategy {
        discardOldItems {
            daysToKeep(1)
            numToKeep(1)
        }
    }

    triggers { pollSCM('H/2 * * * *') }

    factory {
        workflowBranchProjectFactory {
            scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
        }
    }

    branchSources {
        branchSource {
            source {
                git {
                    id('some-id') 
                    remote('https://github.com/org/repo')
                    credentialsId('my-cred-here')
                }
            }
        }
    }

    configure {        
        def traitsBlock = it / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits
        traitsBlock << 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait' {}
    }
}
```

But I am getting error as

```
ERROR: (unknown source) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.MultibranchWorkflowTriggerContext.pollSCM() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [H/2 * * * *]
Possible solutions: collect(), collect(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Versions:
Jenkins 2.319.3
job-dsl 1.77

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
triggers {
    scm('*/5 * * * *')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pratush but that also returned same error

Comment: Can you share the new error, the last one was for an invalid argument type, is this one the same?

Comment: Yes getting same error - ERROR: (unknown source) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.triggers.MultibranchWorkflowTriggerContext.scm() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [*/2 * * * *]
Possible solutions: dump(), any(), cron(java.lang.String), dos(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), is(java.lang.Object), each(groovy.lang.Closure). Tried with - pollSCM ignorePostCommitHooks: true, scmpoll_spec: 'H/2 * * * *', got error for that as well

Comment: try this please :  triggers {
  cron('*/2 * * * *')
}

Comment: I have tried cron method but it unnecessarily builds all the branches even when no commits are there hence pollSCM was the one that was required